# .js file doesn't work in newly rendered form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `Transaction` model with two forms for creating and editing `Transaction`. They are both `remote: true`.
Forms are practically the same with minor differences, so they have mostly the same tags with the same classes and ids.

All the behavior of buttons, fields, dropdowns of forms is described in `transaction.js.coffee` file.

My `edit.js.coffee` is:

```
$('#new_transaction').remove()
$('#t_table').before('<%= j render 'edit_form' %>')
$('#edit_transaction_<%= @transaction.id %>').slideDown 'fast'
```

`edit` action from the controller is also very simple:

```
def edit
  @transaction = current_user.transactions.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.js
  end
end
```

So, when user click on "Edit" button, code from `edit.js.coffee` removes `new_transaction` and renders `edit_transaction` form on the same place.

But all the behavior from `transaction.js.coffee` doesn't work in this new form.
If I copy it to `edit.js.coffee`, it works ok. But it isn't good for me, cause I need to change code in both places, also it isn't good for all the DRY philosophy of Rails (:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that script runs before you modify DOM to include form tags. You may either use [`.on()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (which is tricky sometimes) or after loading form call a function (in `edit.js.coffe`) that you should define in `transaction.js.coffee`